# How can I get the thick code-preview scrollbar back in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I'm not mistaken, in Visual Studio Code there used to be a thick scroll bar on the right side of my code window which you could not only scroll with your mouse, but also see a miniture preview of the code as if it were one long vertical document in font-size 0.5.

How can I get this scroll bar back?

Comment: Do you mean the [minimap](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_preview-minimap)?

Comment: Minimap, that's it. Now enabled. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean minimap: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_preview-minimap?

> To enable VS Code's Minimap, set "editor.minimap.enabled": true to turn on the rendering of a Minimap for the current file.